# In the Pixar SparkShort, “Self”, is there an explanation for where the body parts come from?

Tags: pixar, self-2024

In the short [*Self*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt30833459/) (2024), the main character makes a wish and then body parts start falling from the sky.

Whose body parts are these? Why are they coming from the sky?

Comment: I think the answer in implied in the question. She makes a wish on a star so the star grants her wish to be like everyone else  by creating body parts for her.